# Imported project was not found

Tags: c#, github

I got this error while trying to download open a solution from a GitHub repository using Visual Studio 2019. It says the project file cannot be loaded, and gives me the error:

> C:\Users\asina\source\repos\GrapplingHook\SimplePlatformer\SimplePlatformer.csproj : error  : The imported project "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\MonoGame\v3.0\MonoGame.Content.Builder.targets" was not found. Also, tried to find "MonoGame\v3.0\MonoGame.Content.Builder.targets" in the fallback search path(s) for $(MSBuildExtensionsPath) - "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild" . These search paths are defined in "C:\Users\asina\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\16.0_5ff754ec\devenv.exe.config". Confirm that the path in the  declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk in one of the search paths.  C:\Users\asina\source\repos\GrapplingHook\SimplePlatformer\SimplePlatformer.csproj

I have never had this problem opening a GitHub repo before. I have MonoGame installed. How can I get this solution to load correctly?

Comment: First, check manually all the paths and the configurations mentioned in the stacktrace, on your computer. MonoGame might have not been (re)installed properly. After try to install it again.

Comment: Did you install the correct package for windows? https://www.monogame.net/2016/03/17/monogame-3-5/ => this should install the targets. The error message states, that the targets cannot be found. Maybe the given path `v3.0` is incorrect. Is there a different version installed under `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\MonoGame`?